# Path for NPAPI plugin in manifest file[crx]

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extension, npapi

I am working on a chrome extension, which uses NPAPI plugin in background.html,
NPAPI plugin is installed in /Library/Internet-Plugins.

We want to host the extension on our own server for autoupdate and need to package the extension as crx.

What should be the path for NPAPI plugin in the manifest file.

Thanks,
Swetha

Answer (score 0):

If you're bundling the NPAPI plugin as part of the extension the path is relative to the manifest.json file, meaning if your file structure is:

project root (where the manifest.json is)
    |
  library (subdirectory of root)
    |
  internet-plugins (where your plugin is)

then your manifest should have a similar entry to this:

```
"plugins": [
        {
            "path": "library/internet-plugins/YOUR-PLUGIN-FILE",
            "public": true
        }
    ],
```

replace YOUR-PLUGIN-FILE with the plugin's filename.

The "public" property says if it can be accessed by other pages/extension other than yours.